Source for a dialogue of Galileo about distinguishable dice?
I am reading the Guidi notes on Rota's probability course. On the 117th page of the PDF, Rota mentions offhand a dialogue by Galileo pertaining to the distinguishability of dice:

In real life, we don't have indistinguishable things. (You are, in part, spoiling my act.) Population is distinguishable, until further notice.
What is indistinguishable - you have to prove that. Things in the real world are always distinguishable.
There is a famous paper by Galileo where he is trying to convince someone that when you toss two dice, they are not indistinguishable. They are distinguishable. The probability has to be computed on the basis of the dice being distinguishable. This is one of the dialogues of Galileo. It takes 13 pages.

What paper is this?

The essay in question is titled "Sopra le scoperte dei dadi" ("On the Investigations of Dice"), written prabably between 1613 and 1623, in response to a request for an explanation why in zara game the sum of 10 or 11 is more frequent than the sum of 9 or 12.
For some information about Galileo's studies and a translation of the essay, see Games, Gods and Gambling: The Origins and History of Probability and Statistical Ideas from the Earliest Times to the Newtonian Era by Florence Nightingale David.
The pdfs of the original Italian and translation texts can be easily found on the Web.
